# High Performance BPEL engine?

Tags: performance, bpel

I am evaluating BPEL engine for our high performance telecom application but performance seem to be very poor. We have evaluated  Apache Ode, SunBPEL engine, Active BPEL etc. Do you know any faster BPEL engine implementation or BPEL implementation in C/C++ ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your performance measurements were very brief.

For example, I'm familiar with Apache ODE and I must say there is quite a lot of possibilities to speed things up. 
After doing configuration optimizations, like using in-memory processes and disabling debug events, I got 60 TPS in SoapUI. After I did some code improvements, it went up to 150. So there is field for optimization in future.

I don't know how many TPS do you need, but 60 on a single machine is quite enough.

As for optimizing persistent processes, you need to tune indexes in database.

If you want more details on optimization, you can make a post to [ODE user group](http://markmail.org/search/apache+ode+list:org.apache.ode.user).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Oracle BPEL?  If it's like their database, it's probably fast but hard to configure and administer.